# Приближенное сравнение целых чисел

Tags: c#, алгоритм, сравнение

Мне нужно реализовать алгоритм сравнения чисел в массиве: надо сравнивать 2 числа не с точностью, а с определенным разрывом или процентом.

Объясняю: есть число *7882*, и есть *7872*, диапазон их равенства в пределах **10** чисел, вот мне надо сравнить `A== B ± Q`, где Q = 10, или же какую-то формулу в процентном соотношении.

Comment: `|A-B| <= Q`? что-то вроде этого???

Comment: @Grundy понял, как я сам не додумался))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Для проверки что два числа A,B, отличаются не больше чем Q

```
A== B ± Q
```

Нужно взять модуль их разницы, а именно на сколько они отличаются и сравнить с Q,

```
|A-B| <= Q
```

не строгое неравенство если должны отличаться *не больше чем* на Q.

С процентами аналогично, за исключением того, от какого числа брать процент, ведь делить в данном случае можно на два различных числа. Кроме того нужно будет обратить внимание на случай, когда одно или оба из чисел - `0`